# Progressbar with backgroundworker

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I have the code below to copy some folders over to a different location if the user has the checkbox checked for that folder.

I have a backgroundworker and a progresbar. I see that people on this site and even on MSDN gives the same example to update the progressbar with

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
    // Report progress to 'UI' thread
    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
    // Simulate long task
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

This is all fine and I get the idea on how it works. But what I can't figure out is to implement my checkboxes and copy the folder if it's checked and then update the progress bar depending on how many checkboxes I have. I count the checked boxes and assigned it to prgbarmax.

This is what I have so far:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{           
   for (int i = 0; i < prgbarmax; i++)
    {
        int step = (i / prgbarmax) * 100;
        if (test1)
        {
            //do the copy here
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);                    
        }

        if (tes2)
        {
            //do the copy here
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        }

        if (test3)
        {
            //do the copy here                  
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i);
        }
        .... so on
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using WPF or Windows Forms?

Comment: You need to construct a list of folders to be copied, and copy only one folder at each iteration of the for loop. The problem of your code is you tried to copy all the folders in one iteration.

Comment: @kennyzx I'm very very new to C# and trying to learn as I code. Can you give me a code example?

Comment: @Transcendent sorry.. i added to the question now. i am using Win Forms

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct a list of folders to be copied, and copy only one folder at each iteration of the for loop. The problem of your code is you tried to copy all the folders in one iteration.

To illustrate the idea in code sample.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //construct the list of folder to be copied
    List<DirectoryInfo> listOfFolders = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
    if (test1) 
       listOfFolders.Add(folder1);
    if (test2)
       listOfFolders.Add(folder2);
    if (test3)
       listOfFolders.Add(folder3);

    //begin to copy
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFolders.Count; i++)
    {
        listOfFolders[i].Copy(...); //copy only one folder in the list
        int step = ((i + 1) / listOfFolders.Count) * 100; //calculate the progress
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(step);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But each folder is copied to a different folder. How can I compare the name and do the copy depending on which folder is it?

Comment: En... but that is irrelevant to the original question on backgroundworker. In order to make sure each question/answer has a concrete context,  I suggest you start a new post.